# How to get file upload value in datagrid using OnUpdateCommand?

Tags: file, datagrid, upload

I have this datagrid file upload :

using of this code i got no value.please help how will get value.
I need read hasfile and file name in code behind.

```
<asp:TemplateColumn HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ItemStyle-Width="25%" HeaderStyle-Width="25%" HeaderText="Attachment">
    <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" CssClass="textfield2"/>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateColumn>
```

and my code behind is :

using of this code i got no value.please help how will get value.
I need read hasfile and file name.

```
protected void DGClaimView_UpdateCommand(object source, DataGridCommandEventArgs e)
{     
    FileUpload FileUpload1 = (FileUpload)e.Item.FindControl("FileUpload1"); 
}
```

Comment: Please add "asp.net" tag to your question.